# query.setLockMode("a",lockMode.upgrade_skiplocked) gives a warning in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I  am trying to substitute my sql query that is for Oracle and it is as :

```
select trim(a.id) as id from tbl_insttype a where a.chi_city='1' order by cast(a.id as int) for update skip locked
```

Following is an equivalent hibernate substitution :

```
Query query=session.createQuery("select trim(a.id) as id from TblInsttype a where a.chiCity='1' order by cast(a.id as int) ");
    query.setLockMode( "a",LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

but my log warns that

**LOG:**

```
12830 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  - throwQueryException() : no errors
12846 [main] WARN org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer  - HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 1 arguments encountered
12846 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl  - HQL: select trim(a.id) as id from com.imageinfo.eclear.cfg.xml.TblInsttype a where a.chiCity='1' order by cast(a.id as int) 
12846 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl  - SQL: select trim(tblinsttyp0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from EXPOTDBU_PHILIPPINES.TBL_INSTTYPE tblinsttyp0_ where tblinsttyp0_.CHI_CITY='1' order by cast(tblinsttyp0_.ID as number(10,0))
12846 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  - throwQueryException() : no errors
12861 [main] WARN org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - HHH000445: Alias-specific lock modes requested, which is not currently supported with follow-on locking; all acquired locks will be [UPGRADE]
12861 [main] WARN org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - HHH000444: Encountered request for locking however dialect reports that database prefers locking be done in a separate select (follow-on locking); results will be locked after initial query executes
12877 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select trim(tblinsttyp0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from EXPOTDBU_PHILIPPINES.TBL_INSTTYPE tblinsttyp0_ where tblinsttyp0_.CHI_CITY='1' order by cast(tblinsttyp0_.ID as number(10,0))
Hibernate: select trim(tblinsttyp0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from EXPOTDBU_PHILIPPINES.TBL_INSTTYPE tblinsttyp0_ where tblinsttyp0_.CHI_CITY='1' order by cast(tblinsttyp0_.ID as number(10,0))
```

**12861** says some clear words that i didnt get it right.and the sql query below it also doesnt have any for update skip locked in it.

I dont get what i am doing wrong,should i try some other things?
**PLUS**
it is giving the same error for different lockModes.

Comment: still waiting for a reply !!! its been two hours and only 10 views :(

Comment: What version of Hibernate?

Comment: i am using 4.3 and have tried this on 5.0 too but same thing in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

It says `Alias-specific lock modes requested, which is not currently supported with follow-on locking`, so I think you should try it without aliasing your table with `a`. (There is only one table, is it needed at all?)

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html.The javadoc here only has one method for setLockMode() that is with the alias.cant skip the alias

Comment: what does follow-on locking mean exactly,couldnt find anything on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the HQL parser not recoginze the alias, you have to change hql from `select trim(a.id) as id from tbl_insttype a`  to
`select a.id from tbl_insttype a`  .

I have tried the `count(a.id)` query does not support setLockMode, will throw `could not locate alias to apply lock mode : a` exception.

A simple `select(a) from Entity a`  works.